# Call specific platform function on a Flutter federated plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-plugin

I want to know what should be the best way to have a platform specific function on a federated plugin and how to call it from the main app.

Lets see, for example, this federated plugin code:

- Platform interface where a function is defined:

```dart
abstract class FlutterGetPlatformStringPlatform extends PlatformInterface {
...
  Future<String> getPlatformString() {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
...
}
```

- Android implementation:

```dart
abstract class AndroidGetPlatformString extends FlutterGetPlatformStringPlatform {
...
  @override
  Future<String> getPlatformString() {
    // Some native method
  }
...
}
```

- Web  implementation:

```dart
abstract class WebGetPlatformString extends FlutterGetPlatformStringPlatform {
...
  @override
  Future<String> getPlatformString() {
    // Some native method
  }

  String specificNativeVariable = SpecificNativeVariable();
  
  void specificNativeFunction() {
    // More stuff
  }

...
}
```

So the question here is on my app I import the plugin on my `pubspec.yaml` and then on the code `import 'package:flutter_platform_string_interface/flutter_platform_string_interface.dart';` . So, how I have to call the web only `specificNativeFunction` or how can I set the web only `SpecificNativeVariable` ?

Should I import the `flutter_platform_string_web`, or how I have to instantiate the platform interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this:

- As you've shown, with the plugin client importing `flutter_platform_string_web`.
- Use the pattern demonstrated [in the `in_app_purchase` plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase_platform_interface/lib/src/in_app_purchase_platform_addition.dart), with the plugin client importing `flutter_platform_string_web`. This has the advantage that the client doesn't need to import the entire platform implementation, and is therefore much less likely to think the should call other platform implementation methods directly (which is almost always a bad idea).
- Make the method part of the app-facing package and document that it's only implemented on web. That's how platform-specific methods worked prior to the creation of federated plugins, but it's not really an encouraged practice now. It doesn't scale well as you add more platforms with their own specific methods, doesn't allow for using types that are platform-specific, etc.

Comment: Thanks I used the third option but probably I'll check the others

Comment: Related to this, what should be the pattern to handle if `getPlatformString` is async on some platforms and sync on others? Should I declare async/sync implementations on the interface?

Comment: @selan I'm not clear on what problem you are trying to solve by providing a synchronous version only on some platforms.